# No blog entries in MSE Community Bulletin

Tags: bug, meta, blog, community-bulletin

All over Stack Exchange (both main and meta sites), the Community Bulletin in the right sidebar is showing the recent blog posts from https://stackoverflow.blog, e.g. on Movies:

> [image: community bulletin on Movies.SE with blog posts]

And its meta:

> [image: community bulletin on Movies.SE meta with blog posts]

However, here on MSE... no blog posts at all:

> [image: Meta Stack Exchange community bulletin without blog posts]

Can the blog posts please be brought back to MSE as well?